# Неправильное отображение текста в блоке div

Tags: html, css, faq

Нужно чтобы текст, находящийся в блоке `div`, переносился на новую строку, а не вылезал за пределы блока (именно переносился - `overflow:hidden` неподойдет), и вообще, почему могла возникнуть такая ситуация, что текст не переносится? Ширина определена в css.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 word-wrap: break-word;
```

ВозникаетКогдаВблокОграниченнойШириныПишетсяТакоеБольшоеСловоКакЭто

Comment: абсолютноверноподмечено)))

Comment: такой вопрос уже был и ответ на него тоже

Comment: Спасибо) делал диз для сайта и сделал такую "рыбу" для проверки) думал косяк гдето)) об этом свойстве даже незнал, ещё раз спасибо за ответ) буду лучше изучать свойства css

Comment: уж извините но я нашол только обратный этому вопрос)

Answer (score 0):

white-space: normal;
Случайно нигде не используете 
code или pre?

Comment: спасибо, но первый ответ меня полностью удовлетворил