# Вёрстка текста

Tags: вёрстка, html, css

Пытался сделать вот так: 
[image]
А получилось вот так: 
[image]

Как мне добиться первого варианта? Помогите!

[Второй вариант на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MUhq9/1/)

p.s ваши результаты можете выкладывать туда-же

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Текст в div'е](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/74138/%d0%a2%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b2-div%d0%b5)

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.leftzone {
    width:25%;
    border-right:1px solid #ECECEC;
    float:left;
 }

.rightzone {
    word-wrap: break-word; 
    word-break: break-all;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:75%; 
    float:right;
 }
```

Comment: не помогло

Comment: щас подправил чуток, не заметил крайние элементы

Comment: Кстати а чем табличная верстка не устраивает?)

Comment: уже лучше. остаётся только начало текста вверх расположить. почему то vertical-align не стал вытаскивать текст вверх

Answer (score 0):

Да, это одна из нестандартных задач, решением которых и занимаются Web-программисты. Дело в том, что браузер сам вставляет перевод строки там,где текст в строку уже не влазит( это происходит обычно после пробела, найденного в строке ). Но у вас здесь идет монотонный текст, т.е одни буквы, без пробелов. Именно поэтому у вас такая вот ерунда получилась. Если вам это принципиально неважно, то просто поставьте несколько пробелов в своем тексте, иначе же придется писать пробельный сплиттер на JS или PHP.

---

И, кстати говоря, способ, показанный [[[[@ToRcH565](/users/10415/torch565)](/users/10415/torch565)](/users/10415/torch565)](/users/10415/torch565), работает не всегда и далеко не во всех браузерах. Поэтому и вам и [[[[@ToRcH565](/users/10415/torch565)](/users/10415/torch565)](/users/10415/torch565)](/users/10415/torch565) советую забить на такой вот способ.

Comment: Способ показаный мной работает у меня на сайте для всех 4х браузеров(1 строка опера, второая строка фокс,хром,ие)
Не работает в хроме под мак.(из замеченого).
Экзотичесские брОузеры последнее что волнует))

Comment: @ToRcH565, тем не менее, этот способ очень непрактичен, и он вас, наверняка, обломает в один плохой день, когда, например, вы осознаете, что он не работает в браузерах мобильных устройств.